# JOIN conditions in EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am working on an application that uses EF to access the database. We have a fairly convoluted model and use relationships to let EF automatically join tables into the model objects.

We have a table called `product_data` that links to many `product_attribute` entries. When joining the two, I'd like EF to check the `product_attribute.Delete_Time` to make sure the entry wasn't deleted.

How do I configure such a condition?

Comment: *I'd like EF to check the product_attribute.Delete_Time* -- Simply use `Where`. It can't be part of the relationship configuration.

Comment: Which version of EF are you using? Look at [Global Query Filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/filters).

Answer (score 1):

If you have configured properly the connections between the tables

```
var result = await this.context.ProductData
      .Include(x => x.ProductAttribute)
      .Where(x => x.ProductAttribute.DeleteTime == "deleteTime")
      .ToListAsync();
```